# check if array element is used in a file

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have the following code trying to check if an array element is being used not used: please correct me where i'm wrong. i open the myclass.css and iterate through eachline and add all selectors that start with a hashtag or dot in an array, after  that i split the array element and remove duplicates. after removing duplicates i use this list to check if they are use in a file complied.js if they are not used i add the to a new array.

```
list_selectors = []
file = File.open("myclass.css") 
file.each_line do |line|
    list_selectors << line.split(' {')[0] if line.start_with? '.' or line.start_with? '#' 
end 
while line = file.gets
    puts line 
end
i = 0 
    while i < list_selectors.length
        puts  "#{list_selectors[i]}"
        i += 1
    end
list = []
list_selectors.each { |x| 
    list.push(x.to_s.split(' ')) 
    }

list_selectors = list.flatten
# puts "***************splitted ******************************"
puts list_selectors
# puts "*********** split before dot ************************"
list_selectors.map! { |e| e[/[.#].*/]}

puts list_selectors

# puts "**************remove duplicates ********************"

list_of_classes_ids = list_selectors.uniq
list_selectors.uniq!
puts list_selectors
# puts "^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^not found ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^"


for ic in 0..list_of_classes_ids.length
    puts " #{list_of_classes_ids[ic]}"
end

selectors_not_found = []

while nf = File.readlines("compile.js")
    if !list_of_classes_ids[ic]
        selectors_not_found << nf
else
    puts "Exists" 
end
end

puts "////////*********************************////////////////"

puts selectors_not_found
```

please assist 
when i run the above code it gives this error message `readline`: failed to allocate memory (NoMemoryError) from clean.rb:44: in `<main>`

Comment: So which is line 44??? Doesn't matter. When is this ever false? while nf = File.readlines("compile.js")

Comment: that is line 44 while nf = File.readlines("compile.js")

Comment: Yaeh and it's always true, so blows your memory out shovelling nf into selectors_not_found

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
while nf = File.readlines("compile.js")
  if !list_of_classes_ids[ic]
    selectors_not_found << nf
  else
    puts "Exists" 
  end
end
```

for each iteration you read the file to a new string array, add it to the `selectors_not_found` array, then open the file again (filling up the memory each time)... `File.readlines` never returns a falsey value, so it continues until you run out of memory.

I'm not sure what you *intended* for this code to do (for example what is the value of `ic` here?), but assuming you wanted to iterate over the *lines* in the file, a first step would be:

```
File.readlines("compile.js").each do |nf|
  if !list_of_classes_ids[ic]
    selectors_not_found << nf
  else
    puts "Exists" 
  end
end
```

This code would probably *still not work*, since it doesn't check anything sensible, but your code should stop failing over a memory issue...

---

**Update**

If you want a list of all the words in `list_of_classes_ids` which *do not appear* in compile.js, try doing the following:

```
compile_js = IO.read('compile.js')
selectors_not_found = list_of_classes_ids.compact.reject { |class_id| compile_js[class_id] }
```

Comment: after reading the lines i want to check if the list_classes_ids exist in the compile.js.

Comment: @user3635322, so you need to get a list of ic (whatever that is) out of compiled.js, then subtract that from list_of_classes_ids. That will leave you with any ic in compiled .js that aren't in the css. If you had attacked this with tdd, you would have achieved a much better design and known where your bugs were.

Comment: @Uri i tried that it says it `[]`: no implicit conversion from nil to integer (TypeError) block in main reject main

Comment: @TonyHopkinson i already got the list from css, i need to use the list_classes_ids to check if they are being used in compiled.js, if they used i ignore them, if they are not used i add them to array not found.

Comment: @UriAgassi i tried it, it works but i'm not really sure if it does what i need, i will test it again then will let know if it works properly and give me proper results. Thanks

Comment: @UriAgassi it works properly the remaining thing is that i have to modify a little bit, to get right results. thanks